# Advanced diagram creation software

Tags: web-apps, library, desktop-client, diagram, statistics

To sum it up straight away: First and foremost I am looking for software to create [something like this](https://cdn.sstatic.net/insights/Img/Survey/2019/tech_network-1.svg?v=017e35626eaf) (advanced cluster diagram?) from a data set.

A  (very small) sample data set looks like this:

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|           | Cluster 1 | Cluster 2 | Cluster 3 | Cluster 4 |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| Cluster 1 |         - |         4 |         4 |         1 |
| Cluster 2 |         2 |         - |         2 |         3 |
| Cluster 3 |         3 |         0 |         - |         2 |
| Cluster 4 |         1 |         2 |         0 |         - |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Depending on the number the cluster would be closer together or further away. The more cluster are close to one cluster, the more inflated it gets.

So on a higher level: I need a software (web app, desktop app, JavaScript library,  whatever) to create these types of diagrams from input data I specify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called a network diagram, and you can use (for instance) the free desktop app [Gephi](https://gephi.org/) or [igraph](https://igraph.org/) to plot these.

Usually the input data is given either

- as a nodelist and an edgelist
- as an adjacency matrix *--that's what you mentioned?*
- in other forms

You make these plots by filtering the graphs, and plotting subsets.

I personally would use R and the visNetwork package (which offers a binding to the visJS javascritp library, but this is just my personal preference.
Depending on your data, it can quite a be lengthy task until you get what you want.